# Overpass API - How to get all sustance amenities

Tags: overpass-api

I am using the Overpass API in order to fetch all the amenities. All the amenities are listed on the OSM wiki: [Amenities](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:amenity#Sustenance).

I cannot seem to get this to work. I first have tried `"amenity"="pub;bar;restaurant"`. But this does not work and I need to type out all the types. I have also tried `"amenity"="sustenance"` and `"amenity"="pub~restaurant~bar"`. But none of these return any values.

Answer (score 1):

See the OSM Wiki regarding Overpass QL, especially the section about [Value matches regular expression](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Value_matches_regular_expression_.28.7E.2C_.21.7E.29). The syntax is a little bit different from the one you tried. [Overpass API by Example](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example) is also often helpful and has multiple examples for using regular expressions with multiple values.

The correct query would be: `highway~"^(pub|bar|restaurant)"`